# How to use use foreach operator in pyspark in Structured Streaming (fails with 'DataStreamWriter' object has no attribute 'foreach')?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I use Structured Streaming in pyspark 2.3.4.

I'm trying to use `foreach` operator as follows:

```
query = prediction.writeStream.format('console').foreach(process_row).start()
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataStreamWriter' object has no attribute 'foreach'

What is the problem here??

Comment: What's the Spark version?

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski Spark 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Use Spark 2.4.0 at the very minimum.

According to the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.foreach) of the `foreach` operator it was *"New in version 2.4."*